# URL amigable en Apache obtenida desde un Select Combo

Tags: apache, .htaccess, pretty-urls

Necesito crear una URL amigable a partir del resultado de lanzar un select combo por URL. Actualmente tengo el siguiente formulario

```
    <form action="$path/index.php" method="GET">
    <select name="filtro" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="valor1">Valor</option>
    <option value="valor2">Valor</option>
    <option value="valor3">Valor</option>
    </select>
    </form>
```

El resultado actual es:

```
  www.path.com/index.php?filtro=valor1
```

Alguien sabe qué regla debo concretar en .htaccess RewriteEngine on para obtener el siguiente resultado? Muchas gracias.

```
  www.path.com/valor1
```

Answer (score 1):

Para convertir `www.path.com/index.php?filtro=valor1` en `www.path.com/valor1`, se puede utilizar la siguiente regla:

```python
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #redirect ?filtro=url -> /url
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|[?&])filtro=([^&?]+)
    RewriteRule ^(?:index\.php)?/?$ %1 [R]
</IfModule>
```

En la primera línea, se usa `%{QUERY_STRING}`para obtener el valor pasado en `filtro=`. Por ejemplo, si se utiliza `www.path.com/index.php?filtro=algunvalor`, `%1` contendrá `algunvalor`.

Luego, la regla coincide con `/` o `index.php` y redirecciona a `%1` (el valor que obtuvimos en la línea anterior).

Comment: Gracias. No obstante, aplicando esa regla, qué action="" es el correcto, pues?

Comment: @rafa_pe Recién volví a leer tu pregunta y no estás intentando hacer una URL amigable, sino justamente lo contrario: una redirección cuando se utiliza un query específico. Edité la respuesta para contestar a eso.